# getting screen layout from top of stack

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app that creates notifications even when the app is closed, I would like snowflakes falling down the screen when the notification is clicked, so I need to get the layout of the activity that is on top of the stack.

Is this possible?

Comment: Learning the top stack should be easier than creating snowflakes.

Comment: I understand the activity stack I just don't know how to access a layout I can execute animations on when the layout is not created by my app